# Почему метод get_class_vars() не выводит переменные класса

Tags: php, ооп

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
     interface Shape {public function area();}

     class Polygon {
         private $width, $height;
         public $var;
         function __construct(float $w = 0, float $h = 0) {
             $this->width = $w;
             $this->height = $h;
         }

         public function setWidth(float $w) {$this->width = $w;}
         public function setHeight(float $h) {$this->height = $h;}

         public function getWidth() {return $this->width;}
         public function getHeight() {return $this->height;}
     }

     class Rectangle extends Polygon implements Shape {
         public function area() {
             return $this->getWidth() * $this->getHeight();
         }
     }

     class Triangle extends Polygon implements Shape {
         public function area() {
             return $this->getWidth() * $this->getHeight() / 2;
         }
     }

     function getArea(Shape $shape) {return $shape->area();}

     $rect = new Rectangle(8, 10);
     $triangle = new Triangle(8, 10);

     echo "Площадь прямоугольника: " . getArea($rect) . "<br>";
     echo "Площадь треугольника: " . getArea($triangle) . "<br>";
     $items = get_class_vars('Polygon');
     echo "<br>Переменные класса Polygon: ";
     foreach ($items as $item) echo "$item ";


     $items = get_class_methods('Polygon');
     echo "<br>Методы класса Polygon: ";
     foreach ($items as $item) echo "$item ";

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что так и задумано. Причин сразу несколько, [`get_class_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) делает следующее:

> Returns an associative array of declared properties visible from the current scope, with their default value.

И особое значение имеют следующие детали:

- только свойства класса. Не объекта, но самого класса;
- только доступные свойства из того контекста, в котором `get_class_vars` был вызван. То есть извне класса это будут только `public` свойства;
- только те свойства, у которых есть значения по-умолчанию. У вас у свойства `$var` нет значения по-умолчанию, потому оно и не выводится, хотя оно `public`

В ваших классах ни одно из свойств не имеет значения по-умолчанию. Уже хотя бы по этой причине `get_class_vars` будет возвращать пустое множество.